# Correctly setting stroke-dasharray through CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am having troubling setting `stroke-dasharray` property via CSS (or SCSS):

```
stroke-dasharray: "33.5,0 0,16.5" !important;
```

The error I get is:

> Invalid property value

[image]

Comment: No commas...are required - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray

Comment: Can you please be more specific? `"33.5 0 0 16.5" !important` is still invalid

Comment: Why do you need !important! Without an [mcve] it's hard to help

Comment: I don't really need `important`, I am sorry

Comment: Also the inverted commas aren't required. In fact, that is probably the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you please provide an answer? I am really stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove quote marks then it's valid like this: `stroke-dasharray: 33.5,0 0,16.5 !important;`